# Sequlize js / express js / node js how to change the date format

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

When I see the dates stored in my database.

[image]

This is **normal**. The date and the time that's all.

But when I run a get request to get the data.

[image]

**THIS FORMAT IS NOT SAME AS THE FORMAT THAT STORED IN THE DATABASE**. Why could this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for this kind of work on client or on server

Answer (score 0):

You have selected a data type timestamp with timezone in database that's why it giving you time with timezone

Answer (score 0):

> **THIS FORMAT IS NOT SAME AS THE FORMAT THAT STORED IN THE DATABASE**. Why could this happen?

**Answer to this is :**

When you fetch data from DB , Sequlize js will convert it to the UTC time , and DB UI will show you as your local time zone. So there is nothing to worry about it as its storing and giving the 100% correct date.

**To make it sure :**

You can take the date and time from DB and convert it to UTC , and then you can check that one with result returned by Sequlize js.

To change the Date format you can use **[moment.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment)** , I think this can clear all your doubts

Comment: Dear Vivek, I'm from +05:30 time zone (India/Sri Lanka) I set the timezone in sequlize options also.
My final goal is to compare time against which are stored in the db. eg:- `approved_date: db.Sequelize.fn('CURRENT_DATE')`
if I set the timezone correctly in sequelize js do I need to do this movement js thing also?

Answer (score 0):

We **need not install any package** for these kind of things as we can handle the date formats using MySQL itself
**From your pic I can see you are using MySQL**

Just use dateformat from MySQL

```
Select id, date_format(createdAt, '%d-%m-%Y %r') from table_name;
```

**Note: %r for time with AM or PM**

To dive in deep: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

**For further assistance you can comment down**